# Is there any factors depends for electromagnetic waves?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electronics, electrical-engineering, antennas, microwaves

I am staying in hostel. One person said me that he is getting better connection with the wifi when the door is opened. 
I am wondering that what an electromagnetic wave can do with the door? 
Is there any problem with the very small amount of media that matters about the connection?

Comment: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/6230/

Answer (score 0):

If the hostel door is metal (as most fireproof doors in hotels, etc. are) and the wifi transmitter is somewhere outside the door, then it is entirely possible that the door will affect the quality of the wifi connection. At wifi frequencies, a metal door acts like a mirror to wifi signals.

Comment: It is not metal